Unable to Customize Flutter Toast Message
fluttertoast: I'm using the ^8.2.4 package. I wrapped it with BatteryLevelCubit in my MaterialApp.router widget. In it I check the battery status every minute.
What I want is to be able to show this toast message no matter what screen the user is on. But I have no idea where the flutter icon comes from and why the changes I want are not happening.
What I tried:
void showLowBatteryAlert({required int batteryLevel}) {
    if (!isShowLowBatteryAlert) {
      if (batteryLevel == batteryLevel) {
        emit(LowBatteryLevelState(batteryLevel));
      }
    }
  }

class LowBatteryLevelState extends BatteryLevelState {
  LowBatteryLevelState(this.batteryLevel) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: 'Low Battery Level: $batteryLevel',
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      fontSize: 16.sp,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
    );
  }

  final int batteryLevel;
}

Here's the output

From the Android 12 release, the view of the Toast message has been redesigned to include two lines of text and display the app icon next to the text. If you don't want to show that icon you can try to create custom toast. You can see the custom toast creation process on https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast

Thank you: https://stackoverflow.com/users/14071053/aks
The answer:
From the Android 12 release, the view of the Toast message has been redesigned to include two lines of text and display the app icon next to the text. If you don't want to show that icon you can try to create custom toast. You can see the custom toast creation process on

Feel free to reply if the code is not working
Here is the Modified code:
void showLowBatteryAlert({required int batteryLevel}) {
  if (batteryLevel < lowBatteryThreshold) {
    emit(LowBatteryLevelState(batteryLevel));
  }
}

class LowBatteryLevelState extends BatteryLevelState {
  LowBatteryLevelState(this.batteryLevel) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: 'Low Battery Level: $batteryLevel',
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      fontSize: 16.sp,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
    );
  }

  final int batteryLevel;
}


The reason I say batteryLevel = batteryLevel is to be able to test it continuously. The problem is not there unfortunately :(
